# How does the url work in Django <a> links?

Tags: python, django

Will someone please explain to me what on earth is going on in the Django tutorials when I see this?

```
{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}
```

It's outputting what exactly? The poll.id I understand, is that being passed as some sort of argument or is it appending to the url? How exactly does this work? Is it calling a url.py and iterating over those urls patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`{% url ... %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url) looks up a named URL in your views (url patterns) configuration, and produces a URL that would allow a browser to call that view.

The arguments following the URL id are filled into the url pattern; if the pattern is defined as:

```
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

The `(?P<poll_id>\d+)` group is the first 'argument' to the URL; the tag `{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}` takes this pattern and replaces the first group in it with the `poll.id` value.

Instead of positional arguments, you can also name each captured group explictly:

```
{% url 'polls:detail' poll_id=poll.id %}
```

would achieve the same result.

Because the tutorial included all of the `polls` urls under the `polls/` url path with:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

the final URL generated uses the current hostname and port plus `/polls/` followed by the poll id and another slash. If `poll.id` is `1`, and you access your site with `http://localhost:8000/` that all comes together as:

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/1/
```

Comment: This doesn't function like a normal link does it? It's not just outputting 'http://localhost:8000/polls/1/' is it? If it was just changing the URL I could write something like <a href="poll/{poll.id)/"> the reason its different is because it is actually going off to the urls file and finding the urlpattern that matches right?

Comment: @dlampard: exactly, it generates the link for you based on your configuration. If you were to *change* the URL pattern, then the generated URLs follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be :

```
 /url/absolute/depending.on.urls.py
```

To use it with an "a" just do :

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">Poll {{ poll.id }}</a>
```